# Model size with LinearSVC

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I trained a binary classification model with LinearSVC. I pickled the model for persistence (`protocol=-1`), and the output is a humongous file (several GB).

I don't see any reason for this, there should be just a few float coefficients (on the order of ~10k = dictionary size), with linear classifiers.

My only explanation is that the model stores the support vectors internally, for some reason. Is there any way to delete them to make the model size reasonable again?